# Restoring Database without data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a backup of a very big database.
What I want is to restore this database, but there is not enough space on my harddisk. Since I don't need the data, is there a way to restore it without the data?

I've already tried to script the schema etc. but when I run the script, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you take the backup script without data?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? If it is SQL 2014 SP2 or SQL Server 2016 SP1 or above, you can use [DBCC CLONEDATABASE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177838/how-to-use-dbcc-clonedatabase-to-generate-a-schema-and-statistics-only). It backs up the schema and statistics only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have [RedGate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/)?  If I only had a database backup available, I would run SQL Compare using the backup as source, and a brand new database as the target.  The results of the compare *should* give you what you need, in the correct order of deployment.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Generate and Publish Scripts Wizard to create a Transact-SQL script for many objects. The wizard generates a script of all the objects in a database, or a subset of the objects that you select. The wizard has many options for your scripts, such as whether to include permissions, collation, constraints, and so on.

check here how to generate script-
[SQL Server 2012 copy database without data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880974/sql-server-2012-copy-database-without-data)